# masking a PHP GET url with nginx

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

I have a site that uses php. It is a site that allows someone to search a database, using a PHP GET call. Then it displays all the items that fit the search.

There are many search filters (price, origin site, category). This is what the url looks like after a search where the user entered "blue car" and "dallas"

http://example.com/after_search.php?search_title=blue+cars&search_location=Dallas&price-0=index&price_max=&price_min=&category=every-cat&store=all&max_number=20

Is there a way to make this look like:

http://example.com/s/blue+cars/l/Dallas

without changing any of the GET functionality on the code end?

I also have JQuery running on the site if that is something that can be used to fix this.

NOTE: I am using nginx

**EDIT 1**

Given the advice below this seems to be an nginx question.

Here is my current /etc/nginx/sites-available/default file:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name server_domain_name_or_IP;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

When I simply add this before the last '}' :

```
# nginx configuration
location / {
if (!-e $request_filename){
rewrite ^(.*)$ /array_search.php?path=$1 break;
}
}
```

Which is the nginx converted apache code which is in an answer below, it seems to cause no change.

I have also placed the `list(,$_GET['search_title'], $_GET['search_extra'], $_GET['search_location']) = explode('/',$_GET['path']); // Add more parameters as needed` code in both the index and the after_search php files at the top.

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo. You should change the part that says array_search.php to after_search.php. Then go to `http://example.com/s/blue+cars/l/Dallas` and see if it works. Tell me if you see a 404 error message or if it is loading after_search.php. Also, just to make sure, your after_search.php should be at the root of your site.

Answer (score 2):

**This answer assumes your webserver is running apache and the mod_rewrite module is enabled (usually enabled by default)**

Here is one way that I would approach this. However you will have to add some php code at the beginning of your php file (but you shouldn't have to change anything else in your existing implementation)

First create or edit a `.htaccess` file in the same location as `after_search.php`. Put the following code in the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /after_search.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

This will make it so that the url http://example.com/s/blue+cars/l/Dallas will be rewritten to http://example.com/after_search.php?path=s/blue+cars/l/Dallas behind the scenes (meaning people will still see http://example.com/s/blue+cars/l/Dallas)

Then in your php file, do this:

```
<?php
list(,$_GET['search_title'], $_GET['search_extra'], $_GET['search_location']) = explode('/',$_GET['path']); // Add more parameters as needed
```

This will split the path parameter that we created from the htaccess file and assign each parameter to the appropriate key in the $_GET variable.
You only have to do this one time at the top of your php file and you shouldn't have to touch anything else.

**Edit:** I ran the apache configuration through the "htaccess to nginx converter" and obtained the following code for Nginx

```
# nginx configuration
location / {
    if (!-e $request_filename){
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /after_search.php?path=$1 break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am using nginx.